# html Таблица с пунктиром между ячейками

Tags: html, css

Как можно сделать такую таблицу с пунктиром между ячейками максимально **кроссбраузерно** и **адаптивно** (без флексов, гридов, svg)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю так, но пунктир не до конца доходит:

```css
table {
 width: 100%;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

table td {
 width:100%;
}

table td+td {
 text-align: right;
 width: auto;
}

.table-label {
 overflow: hidden;
}

.table-label>span {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 position: relative;
}

.table-label>span:after {
 content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: -9999px;
    left: 100%;
    color: #cecece;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #cecece;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="table-label">
        <span>
          Lorem ipsum.
        </span>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>
        111
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="table-label">
        <span>
          Lorem.
        </span>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>
        2222222222
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="table-label">
        <span>
          Lorem ipsum dolor.
        </span>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>
        33
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обязательно нужна таблица? Могу предложить маркированный список.

```css
ul.list {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #cecece;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

li span {
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
}

li span.text,
li span.num {
  bottom: -5px;
}

span.text {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 7em;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

span.num {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  padding-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <span class="text">Lorem ipsum.</span>
    <span class="num">111</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="text">Lorem.</span>
    <span class="num">2222222222</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor.</span>
    <span class="num">33</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: спасибо, не обязательно таблица

Answer (score 2):

Еще короче код

```css
p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
}
```

```html
<p><span>lorem</span><span>$9</span></p>
<p><span>lorempixel</span><span>$12</span></p>
<p><span>loremshmorempixel</span><span>$22</span></p>
<p><span>loremdorem</span><span>$11</span></p>
```